# How to personallise songs to fit my voice in audacity

Tags: voice, transposition, audacity

Though I've taken vocal lessons for about a year I'm an inexperienced vocalist (Approx. Range ~D3 - ~D5).

I'm currently using karaoke versions of songs as backing tracks and sing on top of them. For those that are not in a key that I'm comfortable with I change their pitch with audacity (e.g Don't Stop Me Now - Queen, F Major -> D Major).

The result is disturbing as the melody gets distorted and the general outcome feels like my voice does not match the track (or vice versa) while being on key.

What course of action should I take in order to tailor the song to my voice?

Comment: It may be hard to answer this without listening to one of your modified backing tracks so that we can hear *how* it sounds distorted. Don't post an entire song, of course, but I doubt that there would be any problem with posting a handful of 10-second samples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If distortion is the problem, I'd try using a different pitch shifting technique.

I'm not sure which would suit your needs best, but I know that I haven't had complaints using Reaper's pitch shifting functionality:

Right click on audio item -> Item Properties -> Pitch adjust (semitones)